# how to output datetime for next day

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table - timetravel with two columns, trainID (INT) and Date_Time (datetime)

```
timetravel
trainID - Date_time
1 - 2016-02-21 08:00:00
2 - 2016-02-21 12:51:00
3 - 2016-02-22 05:20:00
4 - 2016-02-23 03:44:00
5 - 2016-02-23 06:00:00
6 - 2016-02-24 11:12:00
```

I would like to sort so that the output should only display future which means it should not show todays results

Assuming today's date is 2/21/2016, The output should be

```
timetravel
trainID - Date_time
3 - 2016-02-22 05:20:00
4 - 2016-02-23 03:44:00
5 - 2016-02-23 06:00:00
6 - 2016-02-24 11:12:00
```

Any suggestions? I am unable to use > current_date(), current_time(), and or current_timestamp().

Thanks

Comment: And why are you restricted on the solution?  Sounds like a pretty simple `where` clause...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare your Date_time column to `DATE(NOW())` if you're not allowed to use `CURDATE()` either. If you can use `CURDATE()` use it instead of `DATE(NOW())`

```
SELECT
  trainID,
  Date_time
FROM timetravel
WHERE DATE(Date_time) > DATE(NOW()) ### or CURDATE()
```

Also have a look on the [extensive documentation on date functions in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: That worked like magic. Thank for the assistance and the reference.